# How can I make it so my var is changed to the same as the value in my dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code which draws a parametrical circle and a var that dictates how many points it is made up of. I can't figure out any way to change the var according to what option I pick in the dropdown menu.

```html
<!-- Dropdown -->
<select id="myList" onchange="PointsAmount()">
    <option>2</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>32</option>
    <option>64</option>
    <option>128</option>
</select>
```

```js
var points = 16;
var step = 2*Math.PI/points;
var h = 150;
var k = 150;
var r = 50;

function PointsAmount(){
  var points = document.getElementById("myList").value;
}
```

```js
//Circle draw
ctx.beginPath();

for(var theta=0;  theta < 2*Math.PI;  theta+=step){ 
    var x = h + r*Math.cos(theta);
    var y = k - r*Math.sin(theta);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
}

ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: any error on the console ?

Comment: should be  `points = document.getElementById("myList").value;` inside the function instead creating a new variable called `points`.

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: Tried points = document.getElementById("myList").value; it's still the same

Comment: you should redraw the canvas everytime you change your number of points.
Use a function to draw, and call it on the select "change" event.

Comment: Of course, my mistake, how could I overlook redrawing. I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `var points = document.getElementById("myList").value;`. What you are doing is basically redefining `points` inside the function. All you need to do is to remove the word `var` from the start of the line and it will work as intended.

```js
var points = 16;

var step = 2 * Math.PI / points;
var h = 150;
var k = 150;
var r = 50;

function PointsAmount() {
  points = document.getElementById("myList").value;
  console.log(points);
}
```

```html
<select id="myList" onchange="PointsAmount()">
  <option>2</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>32</option>
  <option>64</option>
  <option>128</option>
</select>
```

You can double check what you did before with calling a function to print the value of points every time the value is changing:

```js
var points = 16;
var step = 2 * Math.PI / points;
var h = 150;
var k = 150;
var r = 50;

function PointsAmount() {
  var points = document.getElementById("myList").value;
  console.log('inner var points=' + points);
  printPoints();
}

function printPoints() {
  console.log('global var points=' + points);
}
```

```html
<!-- Dropdown -->
<select id="myList" onchange="PointsAmount()">
  <option>2</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>32</option>
  <option>64</option>
  <option>128</option>
</select>
```

You can see that the global definition of `points` is always 16, and that the inner function variable you defined there is changing, not effecting the global one. That is the idea of scopes. The `var points` exist only inside the scope of `PointsAmount` but not out of it.